# POST data not showing up in params for custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I have a Rails Route like this

```
resources :agents do
  member do
    post :location_wifi
  end
end
```

And a method in `controllers/agents_controller.rb` like this

```
def location_wifi
    puts params
    puts params.permit!

end
```

I send a POST request to that route with a JSON payload like

```
{ "custom": {"model": "a"} }
```

When i check the params i can't see the POST payload i sent nowhere. The data i am sending here is not being stored in the database but sent to a google API and that result is later stored. For that reason i don't have a model for it.

What is going on here? Why can't i access the POST payload?

Comment: How did you send the POST request? Through a form submit? via Postman? In Rspecs?

Comment: Via Postman. I found the issue which was that i did not send a Content header JSON. I added it but It was checked off in Postman for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that i was not sending a `Content-Type=application/json` header and my API routing namespace defines a `:defaults => { :format => 'json' }`.

Sending the content header fixed it.